# C# windows forms application Word Interop works on Windows 7 but not Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, interop, clickonce

I wrote an application to help users generate letters using C#. I have templates created that are saved in the SQL Server database as rich text. My development machine is Windows 7 and I use Visual Studio 2019 to code the application. I used NuGet to add the interop reference for Word. The application is configured for Release, platform Active(Any CPU), targeting x86. It is a ClickOnce application that is installed from a share drive in a separate directory but the same drive on which the letters are saved.

The application runs properly from my machine but not from a Windows 10 user machine. When it tries to save the file, she gets an error that says "sorry we couldn't find the file". We both have Word 2016. Both machines are 64 bit. I save the letter as a backup in Word and then export to PDF. The code fails on saving the Word document, before the export to PDF. Please see code snippet below:

```
    public static void SaveToWord2(string CoverLetter, string LetterText, string FileSave, 
                                   string BackUpSave, ref string ErrorString)
    {
        try
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            string HeaderFooterFile = Properties.FileResources.HeaderFooterTemplate;

            Document oDoc = new Document();
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(@HeaderFooterFile);
            oDoc.Activate();
            try
            {
                Clipboard.Clear();
                Clipboard.SetText(CoverLetter, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
                oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
                Clipboard.Clear();
                Clipboard.SetText(LetterText, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
                oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();
                //01/26/2021 JS having trouble with the save on Pam's machine so going to try to capture the correct error.
                try
                {
                    oDoc.SaveAs(@BackUpSave);
                }
                catch (Exception exBU)
                {
                    ErrorString = "Error trying to save " + @BackUpSave + ": " + exBU.Message;
                }
                try
                {
                    oDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(@FileSave, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
                }
                catch (Exception exPDF)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorString))
                    {
                        ErrorString = "Error trying to save " + @FileSave + " PDF: " + exPDF.Message;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ErrorString += " and Error trying to save " + @FileSave + " PDF: " + exPDF.Message;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exInner)
            {
                ErrorString = exInner.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(exInner.Message, Properties.LetterResources.SaveToWord, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            Clipboard.Clear();
            oWord.Quit(SaveChanges: 0);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWord);
            //oWord.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorString = ex.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Properties.LetterResources.SaveToWord, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

The error is occurring on the oDoc.SaveAs line but only when running from a Windows 10 computer. Originally, I used the interop from my machine but then changed it to the NuGet interop but that didn't fix the problem. I tried changing Embed Interop Types to False but that didn't fix anything so I changed it back. The Aliases property of the interop reference is global and the Specific Version property is True. I am worried about changing the type of document writer because of the rich text. The rest of the application is working fine for the Windows 10 user. Any ideas?

Comment: Welp, I decided to try OpenXML and I can get the rich text into a Word document. Now I have issues with the header/footer and with exporting to PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenXML did not work out as it would not allow me to properly add headers correctly or export to PDF. I ended up returning to the Word Interop even though I very badly would have liked to use OpenXML. I was able to resolve the problem by setting the reference properties as follows:

Embed Interop Types = False
Copy Local = True

Now the save works no matter which operating system runs the program. I had part of the answer above, but neglected the Copy Local = true piece.